# How do i set a value to x if a random number is in-between 6 - 9

Tags: python-3.x, variables, random

When I run my code, the numbers less than or equal to 6 show up as: **x: 1**. If the random number was 7, it wouldn't say **x: 2**. How do i fix it if the random number was in-between 6 - 9, it would print **x: 2**.

```
import random

for k in range(1,10):
    rnum =  random.randint(1, 10)
    print(rnum)
    if rnum <= 6:
        x = 1
        print("x:",x)

    elif rnum == (6,9):
        x = 2
        print("x:", x)

    elif rnum == 10:
        x = 3
        print("x:", x)
```

when you run code:

```
8
9
1
x: 1
1
x: 1
5
x: 1
1
x: 1
4
x: 1
9
4
x: 1

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you're using `elif rnum == (6,9):` which is not correct syntax. Try using `elif rnum <= 9 and rnum >= 6:` translated to "if x is less than or equal to 9 and greater than or equal to 6".

Comment: `elif 6 < rnum <= 9` would be better.

Comment: I tried to make my code easy to understand, but yes, that is another way to write it.

Answer (score 0):

When you check `elif rnum == (6,9):`, the left hand side is an `int` and the right hand side is a `tuple`.  Equality won't work.

You can check for membership of a tuple with `in`, but the tuple will need all values explicitly:  `elif rnum in (6,7,8,9):`.  An alternative is to use a range, but bear in mind that ranges are non-inclusive for the upper limit so it would be: `elif rnum in range(6,10):`.